# Is there a reason to score on subsets of your data?

Tags: regression, cross-validation, bootstrap

If you're training a model using cross validation on one set of data, and then you're scoring that model on a separate set of data, is it advised to score, say, 1000 times on subsets of your data?

I'm thinking taking bootstrap samples or something, and then scoring the model, then another boot strap, etc.  It seems like this way you'd get an idea of the stability of model performance, but I'm not sure if that's legit or not...

Comment: Random subsets of the test data? Or subsets of the total data (i.e., training + test data)?

Comment: Just random subsets of the test data. Say I have two datasets, A and B.  I want to know how a model built on dataset A will predict dataset B.  So I train the model on A, then score it on B.  Say I've already done a 5-fold cross validation on A and I've averaged the model weights together, and now I need to score this model on B.  Should I just score it on the entire dataset of B, or should I do some sort of sampling and score on B multiple times.